# Financial wellbeing overall components and datasets

Tags: reference-request, data-request, development, financial

I am currently doing a project on financial wellbeing, but on the level of entire countries. I am aware of studies and data pertaining to financial inclusion, as often studied in Development Economics, usually gauged by access to the banking system by seeing the total number of transactions/ number of ATMs in a region/ number of bank accounts/ account holders etc. (see [a](https://www.worldbank.org/en/topic/financialinclusion/overview), [b](https://data.imf.org/?sk=E5DCAB7E-A5CA-4892-A6EA-598B5463A34C&sId=1460043522778) and [c](https://globalfindex.worldbank.org/)).

But financial wellbeing I am told is much broader, and includes control over timely expenses, the capacity to absorb a financial shock, being on track to meet one's financial goals and the financial freedom to make the choices to enjoy life (see [d](https://www.smartaboutmoney.org/Courses/My-Financial-Well-Being-Plan/What-is-Financial-Well-Being)). These seem rather personal to me, and I am not sure if some aggregate measures on the level of nations are available or even which variables to use. There are individual-level primary data questionnaires for measuring financial well-being like [this](https://files.consumerfinance.gov/f/documents/201911_cfpb_fwb-state-report.pdf), used [here](https://fbe.unimelb.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0003/3403722/CBA-MI-Technical-Report-No.-5.pdf) too. The former also aggregates the individual level results into US state-level statistics.

Is such data available at the country level instead of state level, internationally? Any widely used index of a country's overall financial wellbeing?

Also, are there alternatives to using surveys like this, that use other statistics that can be measured at the level of countries, used in the literature? I can imagine using financial inclusion-like data for proxies, for example the percentage of people having a bank account, the average frequency of transactions in the last year from bank/ government data instead of asking in the survey etc. But is there a set of such variables that is usually used in the literature? Any composite measures of the components or maybe of wellbeing as a whole? What are some good usable datasets for this?

Comment: Added links, thanks